# Null check operator used on a null value - twitter auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, twitter, firebase-authentication

I tried to implement twitter authentication and did it 1. after a tutorial and 2 after the documentation... both the tutorial and the documentation used a bang-operator (!) in the code and in both cases the bang-operator led to the error "Null check operator used on a null value" - see image below

[image: Error message]

I made sure to add the scheme to the androidmanifest.xml file and add the callback URL in the twitter app settings - also I made sure the API keys are matching and I wasn't able to find a tutorial to get around the bang operator... I tried to use if clauses to ensure null safety but I still had to use the bang operator, which in the end, didn't change anything. The code to my function is below

```
void login() async {
    final twitterLogin = TwitterLogin(
        apiKey: 't4jz7QiK0tkRQNybk2MKlOa3I',
        apiSecretKey: 'KCwmlETZeLyKWmGlyZdQUXArPfdDj8uEIJqrdCJxZ7XRdpT8Lu',
        redirectURI: 'flutter-twitter-login://');

    await twitterLogin.login().then((value) async {
      final twitterAuthCredentials = TwitterAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: value.authToken!, secret: value.authTokenSecret!);
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(twitterAuthCredentials);
    });
  }
```

thanks for your help in advance:)

---

that's the output I get when I run it with your changes:

```
I/OpenGLRenderer(30256): Davey! duration=41126ms; Flags=1, FrameTimelineVsyncId=13810903, IntendedVsync=184078927234535, Vsync=184078927234535, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=184078927898552, AnimationStart=184078927900531, PerformTraversalsStart=184078927901313, DrawStart=184078928491104, FrameDeadline=184078969956757, FrameInterval=184078927890948, FrameStartTime=11111111, SyncQueued=184078929216469, SyncStart=184078929288605, IssueDrawCommandsStart=184078929574907, SwapBuffers=184078941790637, FrameCompleted=184120054049576, DequeueBufferDuration=3825678, QueueBufferDuration=558334, GpuCompleted=184120054049576, SwapBuffersCompleted=184078942707877, DisplayPresentTime=-6758907574315243998,
```

---

Edit 2
Im now getting an HttpException: Failed Forbidden error... Ive had it before but I sadly wasn't able to find a solution to it since I don't have a clue where it comes from - see screenshot below

[image: HttpException: Failed Forbidden]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try like this;

```dart
void login() async {
    final twitterLogin = TwitterLogin(
        apiKey: 't4jz7QiK0tkRQNybk2MKlOa3I',
        apiSecretKey: 'KCwmlETZeLyKWmGlyZdQUXArPfdDj8uEIJqrdCJxZ7XRdpT8Lu',
        redirectURI: 'flutter-twitter-login://');

    await twitterLogin.login().then((value) async {
final authToken = value.authToken;
final authTokenSecret = value.authTokenSecret;
if (authToken != null && authTokenSecret != null){
final twitterAuthCredentials = TwitterAuthProvider.credential(accessToken: authToken, secret: authTokenSecret);
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(twitterAuthCredentials);
}
    });
  }
```

Comment: thanks this worked for the bang operator issue... but now when I tap on the button I get redirected as normal but there is no new user in firebase... I had this issue before and I made a separate question for it but since I don't get any real error I don't know how to find a solution to that... have you by any chance ever encountered this issue?

Comment: I added the only output I really get above...

Comment: I tried a few things and it didn't work but somehow it got even worse... Im now getting an httpexception "failed forbidden" and I don't know where this is coming from since I've never worked with it... I added everything above - would be great if you could take a look at it

Comment: That isn't an error just warning. So, have you tried to add a print or debug points to the inside If condition?

Comment: Do you mean in the if statement that solves the bang operator issue? I get the dialogue to log into my twitter account but after continuing my app breaks

Comment: When you add print after "await FirebaseAuth.instace**" line, can you see print log?

Comment: sadly not - i just get the HTTP exception